# Jquery content fade help!

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have a news ticket fader in my home page. My html is like this:

```
<div id="news-conteiner">
  <div id="fader-cont-0">
   <div class="short-news">some txt</div>
   <div class="short-news">some txt</div>
   <div class="short-news">some txt</div>
  </div>
  <div id="fader-cont-1">
   <div class="short-news">some txt</div>
   <div class="short-news">some txt</div>
   <div class="short-news">some txt</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need show first 3 #fader-cont-0 > .short-news, after 3 sec fadeOut one by one, then when the first 3 are hidden, fadeIn the #fader-cont-1 > .short-news one by one etc... Someone know a plugin or the easy way for do it???

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) and [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) should do this for you.

Have you got any code already?